# Session lost and Page().User.Identity.IsAuthenticated = false on WebService call

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, flash

Here is my problem:

Im logued

On aspx:

> - (In aspx) myclass.User.Id --> ok
> - (In myclass) Page().User.Identity.IsAuthenticated = true
> - (In myclass) Page().Session["User"] == "myUser"

So far so good, but then, with a *SWF* I call a 
webservice:

> - (In webservice) myclass.User.Id --> null
> - (In myclass) Page().User.Identity.IsAuthenticated = false
> - (In myclass) Page().Session["User"] == null

why the same things return diferent values in the same session?

why Im losing session?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I just realized that the call to webservice does a swf, not ajax.
no way to maintain session?

Thanks!

Comment: The webservice runs within another account and therefor is not logged in

Comment: but the class is the same, not maintain the session?

Comment: can you post some code example please

Answer (score 0):

try using **HttpContext.Current.Session** to reach session variables in your webservice code..

Comment: yes, but maybe I explain bad, the problem i got it in the class (im gonna edit the question)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are enabling the Session for the web service method.

You can actually use the option [EnableSession](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webmethodattribute.enablesession.aspx) of the attribute `WebMethod` for that like in the following sample:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
public void SomeMethod() {
    // here you do some manipulation based on data stored in session
}
```